# Solving Linear Inhomogeneous System of Differential Equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Let $x(t),y\in \mathbb{R}^p,A\in \mathbb{R}^{p\times p}$, I want to solve the following system
\begin{align}
\frac{dx(t)}{dt}&=-A(x(t)-y)
\end{align}
with known $x(0)$. I have 'something' but I suspect that it is wrong. I first take
\begin{align}
\frac{dx(t)}{dt}+Ax(t)&=Ay\\
\exp(At)\frac{dx(t)}{dt}+\exp(At)Ax(t)&=\exp(At)Ay\\
\frac{d}{dt}\exp(At)x(t)&=\exp(At)Ay\\
\exp(At)x(t)&=x(0)+\int_0^t \exp(As) ds Ay\\
\exp(At)x(t)&=x(0)+[\exp(At)-I]Ay\\
x(t)&=\exp(-At)[x(0)-Ay]+Ay
\end{align}

However I have reason to believe (from looking at some other material) that the answer 'should' be
\begin{align}
x(t)&=\exp(-At)[x(0)-y]+y
\end{align}

Are either of these answers (either the one I derived or the one I suspect) correct? If the latter is correct, why? If neither are correct, what is the true answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There was some error in your calculation - I fixed it below..

I give complete calculation for everyone's understanding..

Let $x(t),y\in \mathbb{R}^p,A\in \mathbb{R}^{p\times p}$ .

To solve the differential equation:
$$
{dx \over dt} = - A [x(t) - y]
$$
with known $x(0)$.

We rewrite it as
$$
{dx \over dt} + A x(t) = A y
$$

$$
\exp(A t) \ {dx \over dt} + \exp(A t)  A x(t) = \exp(A t) A y
$$
*i.e.*
$$
{d \over dt}[\exp(A t) x(t)] = \exp(A t) A y
$$

Integrating both sides, we get
$$
\exp(A t) x(t) = x(0) + \int\limits_{0}^t \exp(A s) A y ds 
$$
*i.e.*
$$
\exp(A t) x(t) = x(0) + \left[\exp(A s) y \right]_0^t = x(0) + \exp(A t) y - y
$$

This can be rewritten as
$$
x(t) = \exp(-A t) [ x(0) + \exp(A t) y - y] = y + \exp(- A t) [x(0) - y]
$$

Answer (score 5):

Note when computing the integral that $\frac{d}{ds} \exp(As)$ is equal to $\exp(As) A$, not just $\exp(As)$, so your second-to-last line should be $\exp(At) x(t) = x(0) + [\exp(At)-I] y$ (with just $y$, not $Ay$). So the second answer is the correct one.

Comment: Thanks for pointing my mistake. My screen reader misses too often the  super/under scripts